# symfony 4 setting cookie -> invalid cookie name?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

Trying to set a cookie and getting an error at set

> Warning: Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'

but my name `selector` is ok ?

```
$cookie = new Cookie('selector', $cookieData, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/', null, false, false);        
setCookie($cookie);
```

Comment: Are you positive that you do not have some sort of non-printable char right there within the name?

Comment: Fun thing: this message does not seem to originate from `symfony/http-foundation`, as message should be `The cookie name "%s" contains invalid characters.`. Have you imported the right `Cookie` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setcookie` is a PHP function that is not intended to work with the Symfony `Cookie` class. Technically your code should not even be working because the PHP function is actually all lowercase like this: `setcookie`. You should be getting an error for undefined function because `setCookie` is a method of the `Response` object. It's not global.

Anyway, If you want to use the Symfony framework you will need to set the cookie like this using the `Response` object:

`$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);`

If you want to use just PHP you would set the cookie like this:

`setcookie('selector', $cookieData, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good point, I actually ignored the missing `$response->headers->` as I thought it may have been cut out during the copy-paste... :-/ And camelCase `setCookie` did not help either...

Comment: That's another good point actually. I assumed the error was due to PHP trying to convert the cookie object into a string, which would create the invalid characters.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason. The `Cookie` class has a `__toString()` method which will be called here by PHP implicitly. And since PHP is case-insensitive when it comes to function names it doesn't matter if you call `setCookie()` or `setcookie()`.